# Removing break and continue statements

Tags: c, break, continue

Can anyone recommend an alternative to my break and continue statements? I know it is good practice not to use them. I am thinking of using a do while however, that would make the condition messy. Is there a cleaner way of doing this? I am using C. Due to requirements I cannot have either of them.

```
int inCmpStr( char *a, char *b)
{   
    int i;
    for (i = 0 ; a[i] && b[i]; ++i){
        if (a[i] == b[i] || (a[i] ^ 32) == b[i]){
            continue;
        }
        else {
            break; 
        }
    }
    if(a[i] == b[i]){
        return 0;
    }
    if ((a[i] | 32) < (b[i] | 32)){
        return -1;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: You don’t need an explicit `continue` if there’s nothing else in the loop, so invert the condition and `break` only. Also, `break` and `continue` aren’t bad practice by themselves.

Comment: @Ry- Unfortunately, I need them completely removed due to specifications.

Comment: What kind of specifications? If they ban `break` and `continue`, they’re probably stupid, but I understand that sometimes we have no choice but to conform to stupid specifications :)

Comment: @Ry- professor deducts points for just having them anywhere in the program.

Comment: @Ry-: I do not understand comments complaining about specifications like this. They are obviously from a school assignment, and instructors often specify not to use X part of the language because they want you to learn about Y part of the language. It is a common technique not just in computer science but in almost any subject. For example, photography instructors will assign projects not to use color or to use restricted lighting. The goal is to teach, not to solve a real-world problem.

Comment: I hope that isn't meant to be a case-insensitive string comparison function.

Comment: Rethink "I know it is good practice not to use [break and continue]"; it may be necessary to follow the specification for a particular assignment (or for your whole course), but they are provided by the language for a reason — they are sometimes useful. The `break` statement is very important inside a `switch`.  The way you used them isn't idiomatic C, and you will use `break` far more often than you use `continue`, but using them is not automatically wrong in the real world (as opposed to your course).  Indeed, they're usually preferable to the alternatives such as using `goto` and a label.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Until the “professor” comment, it unfortunately wasn’t obvious that this was from a school assignment. And although it is, there’s a good chance it’s *not* that the goal is to teach, but rather that the professor is misinformed.

Comment: @Ry -- I really wish we wouldn't jump to conclusions that professors are misinformed or worse so quickly based on what students post in questions and comments on SO; there is always a better chance that the students have misunderstood something said by the professor.

Comment: @DavidBowling: Which is why I asked “What kind of specifications?”… and saying there remains a “good chance” is not jumping to conclusions but simply a fact.

Answer (score 3):

You can use sub function to avoid use break and continue.

```
int cmpChar(char a, char b) 
{
    if (a == b || (a ^ 32) == b) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (a == b) {
        return 0;
    }

    if ((a | 32) < (b | 32)){
        return -1;
    }

    return 1;
}

int inCmpStr( char *a, char *b)
{   
    int i;
    int result;

    for (i = 0 ; a[i] && b[i]; ++i){
        result = cmpChar(a[i], b[i]);
        if (result != -1) {
            return result;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I cannot have either in my code due to specifications.

Comment: Can't you use sub function?

Comment: @Dstang: If you're suffering from weird rules, you _must_ tell us what the weird rules are.  People will use the whole language unless there's an explicit instruction not to do so.  The 'no sub-functions' rule had better be a temporary rule for your assignment.  Otherwise, you might do better abandoning this course — the rules are peculiar and not realistic in the real world.

Comment: @sundb I meant both as in break or continue statements.

Comment: @DstangIf you don't want to use break or continue, it's more appropriate to use submethods.

Answer (score 3):

This code:

```
for (start; X; increment)
    if (Y)
        continue;
    else
        break;
```

is equivalent to:

```
for (start; X && Y; increment)
    ;
```

Therefore, you can use:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; a[i] && b[i] && (a[i] == b[i] || (a[i] ^ 32) == b[i]); ++i)
    ;
```